# Can someone explain how they derive a consequence from the axion of choice

Tags: logic, axiom-of-choice

To give you guys the context: This isn’t for anything specifically, however, I hear the phrase such and such “…then we invoke the axiom of choice…” or something like, “…but by the axiom of choice, we derive Zorn’s lemma” or anything along those lines.

My question: How did the axiom of choice have anything to do with what they are saying? Literally, the only time the axiom of choice is ever invoked in my life has been only at times where I do not see how it would be implied. Intuitively, I understand what the the basic descriptions are, but I logically cannot follow the axiom of choice whenever a professor or a professional ever uses the term.

I get there is some subtle point I’m missing, but I’m trying to understand how the axiom of choice is ever implied.

Let me phrase it this way: If I was talking to someone, and I was explaining the logic behind something, when do I tell the other person that I am invoking the axiom of choice?

Comment: "How did the axiom of choice have anything to do with what they are saying?" It depends on what they're saying. I recommend picking a particular argument which uses choice and focusing on understanding that specific application first. Your question as posed right now is far too general.

Comment: Honestly, the generality is intended. But I will give a few examples https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Kagy_cX4hDs&pp=ygUSQWxnZWJyYWljIGsgdGhlb3J5 at time 8:50

Comment: Another example is how it implies Zorn’s Lemma

Comment: Yes, I know when it comes to picking stuff out, however, Wikipedia says “ The axiom of choice is avoided in some varieties of constructive mathematics, although there are varieties of constructive mathematics in which the axiom of choice is embraced.”” But, then, how do you even construct? And how do I know I need to invoke it?

Comment: How the Axiom of Choice implies Zorn's Lemma it's not just an easy observation. It's a complicated theorem. One usually take for granted the axioms of ZF, then assuming also the Axiom of Choice one proves the Zorn's Lemma. It's an important, difficult and deep theorem, so don't expect to simply see what have to do one thing with the other. You can find how the Axiom of Choice implies the Zorn's Lemma (or other consequences) in many Set Theory books.

Comment: To understand that the AC is used to get an equivalence from a fully faithful, essentially surjective functor, you need to 1) understand the argument that there's an equivalence 2) understand what the AC is 3) go through the argument and pinpoint where AC is used. (In general you need to also understand some nontrivial conseqences of the axiom of choice to see if they're used in step 3, but for this particular case choice is used in its plain vanilla form.) If your question is just 'what does the AC say?'... read up on that.

Comment: The axiom of choice is needed whenever you have to make infinitely many choices in a proof.  Mathematical logic, at its base, has a rule of inference called "existential instantiation" which permits making one choice in proof.  From this you can establish by induction the possibility of making finitely many choices in a proof.  However, if you need to make infinitely many choices - it can't be done unless you assume it can - and that's what the axiom of choice is for.

Comment: A simple application AC: Suppose we have have a surjective function $f: A \to B$. Using AC among other axioms of set theory, we can prove the existence of function $g: B \to A$.

Comment: @DanChristensen Assume you meant prove the existence of *an injective* function $B\to A$ (or perhaps that $g$ is a right-inverse for $f$).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Mine is a simpler example. Informally, if you look at each element of  $B$, it has at least of one pre-image in $A$ under $f$. You only need to pick one  pre-image for each element of B. This picking of one element from each set of pre-images is allowed by AC. Formally, using a form of natural deduction and set theory, it took me only 347 lines of excruciating detail to prove it (available on request).

Comment: @DanChristensen you are describing a right inverse of $f$ which indeed requires choice (is equivalent in general). Above, you just said “prove the existence of a function $g:B\to A$” which is easy to do without choice (e.g. constant functions clearly exist).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Re: "...easy to do without choice..." I would like to see a formal proof based on set theory without AC. Yes, I know, that this is all "intuitively obvious," but if it is not an axiom or theorem in some formal system without AC, we cannot really accept it in mathematics.

Comment: @DanChristensen like for any $a\in A$ the set $g=B\times\{a\}$ is a function from $B\to A$ (the only way this could fail is if $A$ is empty, but then we’d need to have $B$ empty too if there’s a surjection $A\to B$, so $g=\emptyset$ will work). There is no AC here and it just uses the normal set operations… everything is formalizable in ZF.

Comment: @DanChristensen What requires choice is the conclusion that there is an injective $g$ (this is the partition principle which is possibly equivalent to AC… open question). Your construction does one better and produces a (necessarily injective) $g$ such that $g\circ f$ is the identity on $A$. And “every surjective $f$ has a such a $g$” is equivalent to AC.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Good point. Thanks. A better example would be my 541 line formal proof that, if you have a surjection $f: A\to B$ then you can prove the existence of an injection $g: B\to A$. (Link available on request.)